# Error installing FirePHPCore

Tags: pear, ubuntu-14.04, firephp

I am working off a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and cannot install firephp due to error:

```
#pear install firephp/FirePHPCore

downloading FirePHPCore-0.3.2.tgz ...
Starting to download FirePHPCore-0.3.2.tgz (25,019 bytes)
.........done: 25,019 bytes
could not extract the package.xml file from "/build/buildd/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/pear-build-download/FirePHPCore-0.3.2.tgz"
Download of "firephp/FirePHPCore" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "firephp/FirePHPCore"
Download failed
install failed
```

I've installed this on several other servers in the same fashion with no problems but they were all running Ubuntu 12 or earlier.

Any advice on how to get this working?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers.  I ended up installing this manually and as it's already installed I can't exactly say if any of these solved my problem or not but I've upvoted your answers as a matter of courtesy.

Answer (score 2):

Use option --nocompress

pecl install --nocompress packagename

Is the only one solution that has worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is working fine for me:

```
$ sudo pear install firephp/FirePHPCore
downloading FirePHPCore-0.3.2.tgz ...
Starting to download FirePHPCore-0.3.2.tgz (25,019 bytes)
.........done: 25,019 bytes
install ok: channel://pear.firephp.org/FirePHPCore-0.3.2
```

Which version of PEAR are you using?

```
$ pear version
PEAR Version: 1.9.4
PHP Version: 5.5.3-1ubuntu2.3
Zend Engine Version: 2.5.0
```

You may need to upgrade, if necessary.

Comment: PEAR Version: 1.9.4
PHP Version: 5.5.9-1ubuntu4
Zend Engine Version: 2.5.0
Running on: Linux tao 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:08:14 UTC 2014 i686

Answer (score 1):

You're hitting a bug in Archive_Tar with PHP 5.5.x.

See [my blog post](http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/pear-php-5.5.htm) on how to solve it.